# How to Mock repository Items in ATG

Tags: java, mocking, atg, atg-droplet

I am trying to create a Mock class for droplet. I am able to mock the repository calls and `req.getParameter` but need help on how to mock the repository item list from the repository. Below is the sample code.

```
for (final RepositoryItem item : skuList) {
    final String skuId = (String) item.getPropertyValue("id");
    final String skuType = (String) item.getPropertyValue("skuType");
    if (this.isLoggingDebug()) {
        this.logDebug("skuType [ " + skuType + " ]");
    }
    final String skuActive = (String) item.getPropertyValue("isActive");
    if EJSD.equalsIgnoreCase(skuType) && (skuActive.equals("1"))) {
        eSkuList.add(item);
        skuCode = (String) item.getPropertyValue(ESTConstants.SKU_MISC1);
        } else (PJPROMIS.equalsIgnoreCase(skuType) && skuId.contains("PP") && (skuActive.equals("1"))) {
        personalSkuList.add(item);
        String tmp = "";
        if (skuId.lastIndexOf("-") &gt; -1) {
            tmp = skuId.substring(skuId.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            tmp = tmp.toUpperCase();
            if (this.getDefaultDisplayNameMap() != null) {
                String val = this.getDefaultDisplayNameMap().get(tmp);
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(val)) {
                    displayNameMap.put(skuId, val);
                    } else {
                    val = (String) item.getPropertyValue("displayName");
                    displayNameMap.put(skuId, val);
                }
                } else {
                final String val = (String) item.getPropertyValue("displayName");
                displayNameMap.put(skuId, val);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where does 'skuList' come from? A simple way to start this would be to create a couple of `RepositoryItem` and then add them to a list and then mock the individual responses of the `getPropertyValue(String)` for each one of these `RepositoryItem` in the list. Also the [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) doesn't show what you want to test from the output. Is this the `service` method in your droplet or is this a utility method?

Comment: Thanks 
radimpe .  This method is in my droplet and skulist is the list of repositoryItems

Comment: You need to create mock objects and then stub each call. e.g. when(repositoryItemMock.getRepositoryId("id")).thenReturn(yourSkuId);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a multitude of ways to 'mock' the list. I've been doing it this was as I feel it is more readable.

```
    @Mock private RepositoryItem   skuMockA;
    @Mock private RepositoryItem   skuMockB;

    List<RepositoryItem> skuList = new ArrayList<RepositoryItem>();

    @BeforeMethod(groups = { "unit" })
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        testObj = new YourDropletName();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        skuList = new ArrayList<RepositoryItem>();
        skuList.add(skuMockA);
        skuList.add(skuMockB);


        Mockito.when(skuMockA.getPropertyValue("id")).thenReturn("skuA");
        Mockito.when(skuMockA.getPropertyValue("skuType")).thenReturn(ActiveSkuDroplet.EJSD);
        Mockito.when(skuMockA.getPropertyValue(ESTConstants.SKU_MISC1)).thenReturn("skuCodeA");
        Mockito.when(skuMockA.getPropertyValue("displayName")).thenReturn("skuADisplayName");

        Mockito.when(skuMockB.getPropertyValue("id")).thenReturn("skuB-PP");
        Mockito.when(skuMockB.getPropertyValue("skuType")).thenReturn(ActiveSkuDroplet.PJPROMIS);
        Mockito.when(skuMockB.getPropertyValue(ESTConstants.SKU_MISC1)).thenReturn("skuCodeB");
        Mockito.when(skuMockB.getPropertyValue("displayName")).thenReturn("skuBDisplayName");
    }
```

So when you then call this within a test it will be something like this:

```
Mockito.when(someMethodThatReturnsAList).thenReturn(skuList);
```

So the key really is that you are not `mocking` the `List` but instead the contents of the `List`.

Comment: Have one confusion in the code Abhishek shared. There is a for loop which is in Java5 way. The declaration/assignation of RepositoryItem is within the loop. How we can mock this RepositoryItem ??

Comment: @Saurabh The loop iterates over the items that exist in the `skuList` that was setup in the `@BeforeMethod` so as long as the `skuList` contains `RepositoryItem` it will already exist as your 'mocked' `RepositoryItem`. You don't need to mock it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a mock using mockito is a good option.
But I am here explaining a different way of mocking the repository item.

Create a common implementation for `RepositoryItem`, say `MockRepositoryItemImpl` like this in your test package.

```
Public MockRepositoryItemImpl implements RepositoryItem {

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    MockRepositoryItemImpl(){
        properties = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @override
    public Object getPropertyValue(String propertyName){
        return properties.get(propertyName);
    }

    @override
    public void setPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue){
        properties.put(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Use this implementation to create the mock object in your test case.

```
RepositoryItem mockSKU = new MockRepositoryItemImpl();
mockSKU.setPropertyValue("id", "sku0001");
mockSKU.setPropertyValue("displayName", "Mock SKU");
mockSKU.setPropertyValue("skuType", "Type1");
mockSKU.setPropertyValue("isActive", "1");
```